# Create table by measure in pbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I'm novice in Power BI and I wanna create table(visualization) by using measures in my report. How many values ​​can a measure return. Is it possible at all?
Mb there is some another solution in my case.

So I have  visualization like this
[image: visualization_1]
, that stretches from SQL query1, and I have SQL query2 which details information for visualization in picture. So I wanna make something like this:
[image: visualization_full].

Query1 for my visualization in first picture, stretches with query2(table in second picture) by unique contract code, but as I understand, filter on my visualization, from picture 1, has no influence on table (from query2). So I tried to change connections of my queries, but it doesn't work enough.

So, how can I make it,
I will be glad to any ideas or suggestions

Comment: Requirements are very unclear :(

Comment: I have edited description of my case, please, check it out.

Comment: Best way to ask a question is - Show your sample data, then show what output you need from them and finally show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I will try it, thnx

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using bookmarks.
Some usefull sources.
[source1](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/show-or-hide-a-power-bi-visual-based-on-selection)
[source2](https://visualbi.com/blogs/business-intelligence/toggle-chart-table-power-bi)
[source3](https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/how-to-hide-and-show-visuals-in-power-bi)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).